# Column borders and the header do not align

Tags: html, header

I'm having an issue where the column borders and the header do not aligned.  I've attached a couple of screen shots (and circled the issue) to illustrate the problem.  I'm doing the formatting within the basic html table.  I have NO IDEA why this may be happening.  Would you be able to nudge me in the right direction to where at least begin to look for the issue?

Many thanks.
[misaligned headers[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWt6A.jpg)

Comment: Not without seeing the code.....

Comment: I highly suggest reading [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking any more questions because with this one you didn't offer any relevant info, code, or an effort to do a little bit research yourself. In order for others to help you and for future visitors to take advantage of already existing answers, it all needs to be as clear as possible.